# Power-Automate Flow query lookup threshold issue SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have read the other inputs about lookup column threshold to a SharePoint list from Power automate. I have created a very limited view of my list and can get the item without any threshold limit. Now I want to update a column in the list further down in the Flow, but here I get stucked again with the lookup threshold as reason. Can anyone tell me, what I'm missing, or isn't it possible to do any updates in a list with to many lookup columns regardless of how the view is?

Answer (score 0):

1. With Microsoft power automate when try to retrieve items from a SharePoint list which as more than 12 looks column you will receive 'lookup column threshold' error
2. In Microsoft Sharepoint following column types are defined as lookup columns:

   a. Standard lookup columns

   b. Managed metadata columns

   c. People and groups Columns

   d. Workflow Status columns

   e. System generated fields

   f. Created by and Modified by

   g. Name (linked to Document)

   i. Link (Edit to edit item)

   j. Name (linked to Document with edit menu)

   k. Type (icon linked to document)

Comment: Would this answer be helpful to you? Feel free to reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Update will not work in your case, use 'Send http request to SharePoint' step and use rest API to update the column